# MS Access Query to show Inventory Counts per Person (Using comma delimited)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to setup a query that will show how many of each ship is owned and who owns it displaying each "Call Sign" who owns the ship in comma delimited format.

The table being used for the query is called "Members" and I'm using a Count function on the "Current Ships Owned" field in the query to get count totals.

The Base query is the following:

[image]

I used VBA to build the following module:

```
Public Function QueryFieldAsSeparatedString(ByVal fieldName As String, _
                                            ByVal tableOrQueryName As String, _
                                            Optional ByVal criteria As String = "", _
                                            Optional ByVal sortBy As String = "", _
                                            Optional ByVal delimiter As String = ", " _
                                        ) As String

    Dim db              As DAO.Database
    Dim rs              As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql             As String
    Dim whereCondition  As String
    Dim sortExpression  As String
    Dim retVal          As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    If Len(criteria) > 0 Then
        whereCondition = " WHERE " & criteria
    End If

    If Len(sortBy) > 0 Then
        sortExpression = " ORDER BY " & sortBy
    End If
        
    sql = "SELECT " & fieldName & " FROM " & "Members" & whereCondition & sortExpression

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly)
    Do Until rs.EOF

        If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(0).Value) Then
            retVal = retVal & Nz(rs.Fields(0).Value, "") & delimiter
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - Len(delimiter))
    
    QueryFieldAsSeparatedString = retVal
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

I then added the field with the owners by adding the following expression to my query:

```
Owners: QueryFieldAsSeparatedString("[Call Sign]","Members",Count([Members]![Current Ships Owned])>=1)
```

But it comes back with the error "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Owners' as part of an aggregate function". Changing it from expression to group by gives an error "reserved error (-3087);"

If I remove the Count from the expression it runs but gives me all members rather than the members that own the ships.

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure what I'm missing but I think some fresh eyes on the issue may help.

Thank you!!
-Deke

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have basically replicated http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

The `criteria` parameter is the problem. It expects a string, but you pass an expression.

And even if Access silently converts it, `WHERE Count([field]) >= 1` is not valid in the WHERE clause, that would only work in a HAVING clause.

But what you actually need there is a criterium that collects all Members records that belong to the current query record.
See the usage example on Allen Browne's page, and the documentation of the `strWhere` parameter.